# How do GANs create an image with specific characteristics?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-model, generative-adversarial-networks, image-generation

I've seen GANs that do things like convert an image to a painting or this GAN here https://make.girls.moe/#/ that takes in a set of characteristics and generates a waifu with those characteristics.

My understanding of a GAN is that the generator upsamples random noise and the discriminator detects if an image is within the real or fake. So if the generator say, generates a waifu with the wrong hair color, how would the discriminator know?